# YouTube Data API - channel IDs changed overnight at 28 of February

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

We are handling several YT channels for our customers via the Data API. Since 28 of February, we are getting strange responses on https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#part and https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list endpoints. In most cases, the response contains an empty items list but returns with 200. It looks like the access token is fine (otherwise it would return with 403 or something similar) but it's not connected to any channel.
E.g.:
 https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?id=&part=snippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatistics
returns with:

```
{
  "items": [],
  "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
  "etag": <etag>,
  "pageInfo": {
    "resultsPerPage": 0,
    "totalResults": 0
  }
}
```

We have noticed a strange behavior in some cases when calling the same endpoint with "mine=true". It gave back channel details in the items list but the ID of the channel in the response is different than the ID we store for the same channel. We tried to call the endpoint with the ID from the response and the access token we store and it worked fine. The "publishedAt" section of the response shows that this channel has been created at "2017-05-19T18:59:45.000Z" so it's not a new one and according to our logs before 2020-02-28 it worked fine with our ID.
These circumstances make me think the ID of several channels has just changed and that's why we are getting these strange or empty responses.

Has anybody else experienced the same issues?

Please note that I'm not talking about items[] in invideoPromotion, I know that part is deprecated.